# Where to find wscript hooks?

Tags: windows, scripting, wsh

I need to automate an IM client to update a status every few hours, basically log in, update status, log out.  I'm trying to do this with windows scripting, but cannot seem to find the proper hook names to the application.  Is there somewhere specific I can look to find this kind of information about an application, or am I merely going about this with the wrong tool in hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IM client are you trying to automate?

Many popular IM services now have their own official API's that you can use to interface with their service programatically rather than having to 'hook' into a client. Third party libraries are also fairly widely available (Google around).

I used the [AIM API](http://dev.aol.com) to write a couple of fairly nifty utilities recently. AOL offers SDK's for several popular platforms including C, Java and C#.

Comment: That got me going the right direction, thanks!